# Combining two LINQ statments into one

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have some LINQ code that I want to run but the criteria depends on whether the country variable that I pass to the function is null or not.

So, if the country variable is null I want to run : -

```
  var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT
                      where new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY)
```

and if country has a value I want to run

```
  var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT where r.COUNTRY == country
```

The question is, is there a way to combine the 2 statement into one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this?:

```
var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT 
              where (country != null && r.COUNTRY == country) ||
                    (country == null && new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use check if `country` has value then create an array using `country` otherwise create using predefined list

```
var arr = string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) 
    ? new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }
    : new[] { country };

var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT where arr.Contains(r.COUNTRY);
```

Comment: These seems more correct, because it will produce better query then my version.

Answer (score 1):

If it really had to be done as a single query, then:

```
var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT
  where (
    country == null ? new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" } : new[]{country})
    .Contains(r.COUNTRY);
```

But why not:

```
var resorts = country == null
  ? from r in db.WRESORT
    where (new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY)
  : from r in db.WRESORT where r.COUNTRY == country;
```

Many databases and other providers can do better with a single equality check (`=`) than a contains (`IN (…)`), and since the type of the query is going to be the same either way, this will work, and produce a query of the same type. What harm that the code branch happens outside of the linq-y bit?

In this case you can also go for the more readable:

```
IQueryable<Resort> resorts;
if(country == null)
  resorts = from r in db.WRESORT
    where (new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY);
else
  resorts = from r in db.WRESORT where r.COUNTRY == country;
```

Because the type parameter of the `IQueryable` isn't anonymous. If you had something like `.Select(r => new{r.COUNRY, r.Name})` then this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score -1):

intersection:

```
var resorts = 
from r in db.WRESORT
where new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY) && r.COUNTRY == country;
```

or

union:

```
var resorts = from r in db.WRESORT
                      where new[] { "AUSTRIA", "FRANCE", "ITALY" }.Contains(r.COUNTRY) || r.COUNTRY == country;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If country == null first version will fail. Second version will return all australia, france , Italy and Brasil if contry == brasil, but OP wants only brasil